# Changing subplot axes range when calling plot_pacf as one of the suplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am having trouble setting different x-axis ranges for some subplots I am making. As far as I can gather, this could be because the `plot_pacf()` function was called instead of using `axes2.plot()`

The code is:

```
# PACF plot of 1st differenced series
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(9,3), 'figure.dpi':120})

# I do not know why the data is defaulting to starting from 1970..but this is my attempt to fix it
x_axis_min = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
x_axis_max = datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30)
x_axis_min_pacf = datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31)
x_axis_max_pacf = datetime.datetime(1970, 2, 1)

fig, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)

# differencing plot
axes1.plot(store1_train.Sales.diff())
axes1.set_title('1st Differencing')
axes1.set_xlim(x_axis_min, x_axis_max)
axes1.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)

# pacf plot
plot_pacf(store1_train.Sales.diff().dropna(), ax=axes2)
axes2.set_xlim(x_axis_min_pacf, x_axis_max_pacf)
axes2.set_ylim((0,1.1))
axes2.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)

plt.show()
```

However the output doesn't set a specific x-axis range for each subplot. Instead it just takes `x_axis_min_pacf` and `x_axis_max_pacf` as the range for both subplots

[image]

(note: I know the x-axis date ranges don't make sense/arent' comparable between `axes1` and `axes2`. That is a separate issue that has led to this question's problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it’s the same issue with `sharex=True` as in your other post here and that is why it takes `x_axis_min_pacf` and ‘x_axis_max_pacf’ for both plots:

[Differencing and Autocorrelation Function plots x-axis extends far beyond dataset range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842851/differencing-and-autocorrelation-function-plots-x-axis-extends-far-beyond-datase)

Secondly, it does not really make sense to set the ticks on the x axis to dates, because the pacf correlation values are not really date related. The correlation works for every observation in the dataset and does not really have anything to do with the date.

Therefore, I would recommend to remove the line  `axes2.set_xlim(x_axis_min_pacf, x_axis_max_pacf)` and use numeric values (representing the number of lags) instead. You can however draw some lines in the pacf plot to increase legibility. Add something like this before `plot_pacf(…)`:

```
number_of_lags=30
steps_with_lines=7
for x in range(0, number_of_lags+1, steps_with_lines):

    plt.axvline(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=1, color="lightblue", linestyle="--")
```

Comment: Thanks @Arne, your help on my recent questions solved my issues. About the  dates as x-axis values, it seems to have sorted itself out into numeric lag values on its own once i removed ```sharex=True```, which could be the doing of the ```plot_pacf()``` function